# How to decode mail body in Go

Tags: email, go, html-email

I'm working on an email client and part of this I need to decode the email body. I'm using the [IMAP](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go-imap/go1/imap) package to fetch the messages but there is no "decode" method. I also checked the [net/mail package](http://golang.org/pkg/net/mail/) with no luck either. Only the headers seem to have a parser. Is there any lib that I can use?

Answer (score 9):

Once you parsed the email with net/mail and have a [Message](http://golang.org/pkg/net/mail/#Message), if the body is quoted-printable encoded (`Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable`):

- if using Go 1.5, use the [quotedprintable package from the standard library](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/quotedprintable/)
- if using an older version of Go, use my [drop-in replacement](https://github.com/alexcesaro/quotedprintable)

Example:

```
r := quotedprintable.NewReader(msg.Body)
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r) // body now contains the decoded body
```

If the body is encoded using base64 (`Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`), you should use the [encoding/base64 package](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/base64/).

Comment: and if it's encoded using a different thing / charset  what should I do ? . See http://stackoverflow.com/q/24902453/3780579

Comment: The [only other encoding that is likely](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Transfer-Encoding) is 7bit. In this case you do not have to do anything.

Answer (score 5):

I've had some luck using [github.com/jhillyerd/enmime](https://github.com/jhillyerd/enmime) to break out both headers and body parts. Given an `io.Reader` `r`:

```
// Parse message body
env, _ := enmime.ReadEnvelope(r)
// Headers can be retrieved via Envelope.GetHeader(name).
fmt.Printf("From: %v\n", env.GetHeader("From"))
// Address-type headers can be parsed into a list of decoded mail.Address structs.
alist, _ := env.AddressList("To")
for _, addr := range alist {
  fmt.Printf("To: %s <%s>\n", addr.Name, addr.Address)
}
fmt.Printf("Subject: %v\n", env.GetHeader("Subject"))

// The plain text body is available as mime.Text.
fmt.Printf("Text Body: %v chars\n", len(env.Text))

// The HTML body is stored in mime.HTML.
fmt.Printf("HTML Body: %v chars\n", len(env.HTML))

// mime.Inlines is a slice of inlined attacments.
fmt.Printf("Inlines: %v\n", len(env.Inlines))

// mime.Attachments contains the non-inline attachments.
fmt.Printf("Attachments: %v\n", len(env.Attachments))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a project like [`artagnon/ibex`](https://github.com/artagnon/ibex/), which uses the [`go-imap` package](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go-imap/go1/imap), does provide that feature.
See for instance its [`artagnon/ibex/imap.go#L288-L301`](https://github.com/artagnon/ibex/blob/ba09ce9cab4ccf6ac34ba2d98e190abb6903692d/imap.go#L288-L301) test.

```
var body []byte
cmd, err = imap.Wait(c.UIDFetch(set, "BODY.PEEK[]"))
if (err != nil) {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    return nil
}
body = imap.AsBytes(cmd.Data[0].MessageInfo().Attrs["BODY[]"])
cmd.Data = nil

bytestring, err := json.Marshal(MessageDetail{string(body)})
if (err != nil) {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    return nil
}
return bytestring
```

Comment: I finally abandoned Go for this project. ibex lib doesn't seem to help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24903176/3780579