# "missing word in phrase: charset not supported", when using the mail package

Tags: email, go, mime-types, mime

I'm trying to parse emails and I get this kind of errors using the mail package. Is it a bug on the mail package or something I should handle myself ?

`missing word in phrase: charset not supported: "gb18030"`

`charset not supported: "koi8-r"`
`missing word in phrase: charset not supported: "ks_c_5601-1987"`

How can I fix them ?  I think I should use [charset](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go-charset/charset) but I'm not sure how
. Here's how an email header looks like

```
Received: from smtpbg303.qq.com ([184.105.206.26]) by mx-ha.gmx.net
 (mxgmxus001) with ESMTPS (Nemesis) id 0MAOx2-1X2yNC2ZFC-00BaVU for
 <sormester@lobbyist.com>; Sat, 14 Jun 2014 18:11:48 +0200
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=qq.com; s=s201307;
    t=1402762305; bh=imEvSr8IPsqWTXU63xUHRv+wuQG+Tcz2mPP9ai4rrE4=;
    h=X-QQ-FEAT:X-QQ-SSF:X-HAS-ATTACH:X-QQ-BUSINESS-ORIGIN:
     X-Originating-IP:In-Reply-To:References:X-QQ-STYLE:X-QQ-mid:From:To:Subject:Mime-Version:Content-Type:Content-Transfer-Encoding:Date:
     X-Priority:Message-ID:X-QQ-MIME:X-Mailer:X-QQ-Mailer:
     X-QQ-ReplyHash:X-QQ-SENDSIZE:X-QQ-FName:X-QQ-LocalIP;
    b=QXs4CveboS8nG6htN9W6amC3X+F7X3ZtFrt6jrjWI+RmbvqBuTCVmX9IlaqCX84H8
     n14x2Wp7x4kDYcNRqhe+HjTpf715TTQXc4d40b9e38frC/5qIhpMtYNsD8iEJwRzHW
     U3xi8Yq7OCIB303fIpytx8tOjexQpZKSHbJ7ecX0=
X-QQ-FEAT: zaIfg0hwV2pIDflZYPQUsuPPXG5wtRVHJU6PiOYLBBA=
X-QQ-SSF: 00010000000000F000000000000000L
X-HAS-ATTACH: no
X-QQ-BUSINESS-ORIGIN: 2
X-Originating-IP: 180.155.99.102
In-Reply-To: <trinity-b7c6d611-52fd-4afa-b739-2deb243532a6-1402761364579@3capp-mailcom-lxa05>
References: <97e07dab7c2d1a005ed928c4350690e0@hotels-desk.co.uk>,
 <tencent_105D3DC11702F53465C0025D@qq.com>
    <trinity-b7c6d611-52fd-4afa-b739-2deb243532a6-1402761364579@3capp-mailcom-lxa05>
X-QQ-STYLE: 
X-QQ-mid: webmail474t1402762303t356131
From: "=?gb18030?B?08bTzg==?=" <38438nx@qq.com>
To: "=?gb18030?B?V2lsaGVsbSBLdW1tZXI=?=" <sormester@lobbyist.com>
Subject: =?gb18030?B?u9i4tKO6ILvYuLSjulBhbGFjZSBXZXN0bWluc3Rl?=
 =?gb18030?B?cjogMDEtMDctMjAxNCAtIDA0LTA3LTIwMTQ=?=
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="----=_NextPart_539C743F_08A07490_0157E268"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8Bit
Date: Sun, 15 Jun 2014 00:11:43 +0800
X-Priority: 3
Message-ID: <tencent_573A737E73016B9F5A3D10C1@qq.com>
X-QQ-MIME: TCMime 1.0 by Tencent
X-Mailer: QQMail 2.x
X-QQ-Mailer: QQMail 2.x
X-QQ-ReplyHash: 170675637
X-QQ-SENDSIZE: 520
X-QQ-FName: 7B2EFFAD16B8462B84D3499A4CC7DDEF
X-QQ-LocalIP: 163.177.66.155
Envelope-To: <sormester@lobbyist.com>
X-GMX-Antispam: 0 (Mail was not recognized as spam); Detail=V3;
X-GMX-Antivirus: 0 (no virus found)
```

Edit:

I've tried to use the [charset](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go-charset/charset) package it but it has no effect. I still get the same error on the same messages.

```
import "code.google.com/p/go-imap/go1/imap"
header := imap.AsBytes(rsp.MessageInfo().Attrs["RFC822.HEADER"])

            r, err := charset.NewReader("UTF-8", bytes.NewReader(header))
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            fmt.Printf("new char is %v", r)

            msg, err := mail.ReadMessage(r)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
                return mgs, err
            }

            mg.From, err = msg.Header.AddressList("From")
            if err != nil {
                log.Errorf("NO FROM msg %s, err %v", header, err)
             return
              }
```

The mail package seems to be able to decode only `rfc2047` but the charset package doesn't support this

```
character set "rfc2047" not found
```

It seems  [mahonia](http://godoc.org/github.com/axgle/mahonia) which could fix the issue?

Comment: Underlying support for GB18030 is in http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.text/encoding/simplifiedchinese and ks_c_5601-1987 is in http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.text/encoding/korean -- there's still work to do to connect that up with header parsing, though, and I'm not familiar enough with the other packages you're using to immediately know how to do that.

Comment: I'm using the imap package from the standard lib to 'fetch' the email as bytes then I use the mail package to parse it and actually get the 'from', to, subject etc fields from header.  It doesn't seem right to me to hunt for different packages and find hacks to support  a specific charset. I think the mail package should do this out of the box. What's the use of the mail.ParseAddress function if it handles only one charset ?

Comment: Honestly, I find your frustration here understandable. Go is generally good at network services and handing characters in all languages, so it's surprising that this was a blind spot.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps someone who may consider Go to process emails(i.e develop client apps). It seems the standard Go standard library  is not mature enough for email processing. It doesn't handle multi-part, different char sets etc.  After almost a day trying different hacks  and packages I've decided to just throw the go code away and use an old good JavaMail solution.

Comment: Interesting, i've nearly burn a day on this too. First Go headache, in a journey that has been mostly fun.

Comment: this answer is Obsolete ... go today has "mime/multipart" which handles creating or parsing multi part messages including SMTP traffic

Answer (score 0):

Alexey Vasiliev's MIT-licensed http://github.com/le0pard/go-falcon/ includes a `parser` package that applies whichever encoding package is needed to decode the headers (the meat is in [utils.go](https://github.com/le0pard/go-falcon/blob/master/parser/utils.go)).

```
package main

import (
        "bufio"
        "bytes"
        "fmt"
        "net/textproto"
        "github.com/le0pard/go-falcon/parser"
)

var msg = []byte(`Subject: =?gb18030?B?u9i4tKO6ILvYuLSjulBhbGFjZSBXZXN0bWluc3Rl?=
 =?gb18030?B?cjogMDEtMDctMjAxNCAtIDA0LTA3LTIwMTQ=?=

`)


func main() {
        tpr := textproto.NewReader(bufio.NewReader(bytes.NewBuffer(msg)))
        mh, err := tpr.ReadMIMEHeader()
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }
        for name, vals := range mh {
                for _, val := range vals {
                        val = parser.MimeHeaderDecode(val)
                        fmt.Print(name, ": ", val, "\n")
                }
        }
}
```

It looks like its [`parser.FixEncodingAndCharsetOfPart`](http://godoc.org/github.com/le0pard/go-falcon/parser#FixEncodingAndCharsetOfPart) is used  by the package to decode/convert content as well, though with a couple of extra allocations caused by converting the `[]byte` body to/from a `string`. If you don't find the API works for you, you might at least be able to use the code to see how it can be done.

Found via godoc.org's "...and is imported by 3 packages" link from [encoding/simplifiedchinese](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.text/encoding/simplifiedchinese) -- hooray godoc.org!

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [github.com/jhillyerd/enmime](https://github.com/jhillyerd/enmime) which seems to have no trouble with this. It'll parse out both headers and body content. Given an `io.Reader` `r`:

```
// Parse message body
env, _ := enmime.ReadEnvelope(r)
// Headers can be retrieved via Envelope.GetHeader(name).
fmt.Printf("From: %v\n", env.GetHeader("From"))
// Address-type headers can be parsed into a list of decoded mail.Address structs.
alist, _ := env.AddressList("To")
for _, addr := range alist {
  fmt.Printf("To: %s <%s>\n", addr.Name, addr.Address)
}
fmt.Printf("Subject: %v\n", env.GetHeader("Subject"))

// The plain text body is available as mime.Text.
fmt.Printf("Text Body: %v chars\n", len(env.Text))

// The HTML body is stored in mime.HTML.
fmt.Printf("HTML Body: %v chars\n", len(env.HTML))

// mime.Inlines is a slice of inlined attacments.
fmt.Printf("Inlines: %v\n", len(env.Inlines))

// mime.Attachments contains the non-inline attachments.
fmt.Printf("Attachments: %v\n", len(env.Attachments))
```