# Go - failsafe charsets from emails

Tags: character-encoding, go

I have a bunch of emails that I decided to process in Go.
Go parse everything (headers, multipart) very well.

How do I convert all emails text to `UTF-8`?

I read encoding name from `Content-Type` field and parse it with `mime.ParseMediaType`

I believe some emails may have bugs in encodings.
e.g. wrong encoding or multiple encodings in single body.

So if there is single wrong character but 99% of text is readable. I wish to be able to read it.

**PS**

There are libs in go to work with charset. https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.text/encoding 
and a set of `iconv` wrappers like https://github.com/djimenez/iconv-go

I think first lacks encodings and it does give decoder by encoding name. I am not sure sure that I know all synonyms of encodings.
e.g. UTF-8 and utf8 are same encoding. Windows-1251 and CP-1251 are same also.

Second is iconv wrapper. Go is secure language and that is why I wish to do that in Go. There is no buffer overflow. But `iconv` is written in C and is less secure. I do

Comment: You will need to provide some code where there is a problem, also strings are utf8 by default in Go.

Comment: This seems like a legit question: e-mails out on the Internet are sometimes encoded in legacy charsets (Latin iso-8859-1, Cyrillic KOI8-R, Chinese GB 18030) and it's not obvious how you convert them to the UTF-8 encoding that Go uses internally. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24902453/missing-word-in-phrase-charset-not-supported-when-using-the-mail-package/24926485 for someone else struggling with this in Go.

Comment: The `parser` subpackage of https://github.com/le0pard/go-falcon/ appears to try to handle both headers (via `parser.MimeHeaderDecode` defined in `utils.go`) and bodies (via `parser.FixEncodingAndCharsetOfPart`). I don't know how easy that'll be to integrate into what you're doing, but it's a lead, at least.

Comment: Exactly there are many libs in go to work with charset. https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.text/encoding or iconv wrappers like https://github.com/djimenez/iconv-go The first is native Go but I think it lacks encodings. Second is not native Go